# Download response file using Newman

Tags: postman, newman

We can use "send and download" option in Postman to download a response file. Do we have any option or command to download a file(eg excel) using Newman command in newman's current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

you may have a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options.
You can use reporters :

add:

```
-r json
```

then add

```
--reporter-json-export <path/file.json>
```

in your newman run command options and it will output a json report file.
If you want other formats, check the other reporters (html, junit and cli) with their respective options.
warning: dont put spaces when you set them (ie. -r cli,json,html)

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently any way to download the JSON response body to a file outside of Postman.  The reporters available for Newman only give the results of the collection query and tests, but do not include the body response of the original GET request.

Comment: has this changed? are there any custom reporters that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not there as of this comment

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/413

A workaround is available in this bug, that might be useful !